# PHP Recursion and How to Get Array Variable to Maintain Value in Recursive Call

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion

I have a commenting system that has top level comments, and each of those can have infinite level of reply comments.  I am trying to get a listing of all the comment id's in descending order into an array.

The PHP/SQL code works fine when I just echo the results out. However, I would like to end up withe the list of comments in the correct order in an array.  It seems when the array variable is passed through the recursive routines, it fails.  I understand this to be a variable scope issue in PHP recursion.

What is the work around then to get what I want?

My code:

```
//get all comments and descendants for post id
function get_comment_list($db,$post_id) {  
        $comment_array = array();
        $sql = "SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE parent = 0 AND _post_id=".$post_id." "."ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
        $result = $db->query($sql); 
        $q = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);//one level array with '0' parameter   
        foreach($q as $parent){
            echo $parent;echo '<br>';//first level parent comment
            $comment_array[] = $parent;//store comment_id's
            get_descendants($db,$parent,$comment_array);    
        }    
    return $comment_array;
}
//get all descendants of parent level comments
function get_descendants($db,$parent,$comment_array){
    $sql = "SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE parent = $parent ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $q = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);//one level array with '0' parameter   
    foreach($q as $item){
        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$item;echo '<br>';
        $comment_array[]=$item;//store comment_id's
        get_descendants($db,$item,$comment_array);
    }
}
$post_id = 199;
$comment_list = array();
$comment_list = get_comment_list($db,$post_id);
print_r($comment_list);
```

When I echo the results, I get what I want:

```
295
  296
  302
  297
  298
  299
  300
294
244
  304
  293
  288
  286
  287
  285
  284
  282
  281
  279
  280
241
  292
  289
  283
240
  290
237
  291
  238
  239
236
230
  235
  231
  232
```

When I print_r() the array, I only get the top level id's.  The descendants have not been added on during the recursive calls.

```
295
294
244
241
240
237
236
230
```

Or if you can suggest a recursive MYSQL query that will do descending order?

Basic data structure is:

```
comment_id    comment    parent   post_id
```

parent will refer to comment_id as its parent.  parent = 0 is a top level parent.

Comment: do you have only one record with comment_id=0 ?

Comment: NO, there can be several parents with parent = 0.  Say for example someone posts a video.  Comments directly to the posting will be at parent = 0.  Replies to the comments will have parent = the comment_id... enabling nesting or hierarchical replies.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around using a session array variable.  It persists through the recursive functions.  Adjusted code:

```
$_SESSION['list']=array();
//get all comments and descendants for post id.  First get parents at = 0, then recurse through children/descendants
function get_comment_list($db,$post_id) {  
        $comment_array = array();
        $sql = "SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE parent = 0 AND _post_id=".$post_id." "."ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
        $result = $db->query($sql); 
        $q = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);//one level array with '0' parameter   
        foreach($q as $parent){
            //echo $parent;echo '<br>';//first level parent comment
            $_SESSION['list'][] = $parent;//store comment_id's
            get_descendants($db,$parent);    
        }    
    return $_SESSION['list'];
}
//get all descendants of parent level comments
function get_descendants($db,$parent){
    $sql = "SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE parent = $parent ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $q = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);//one level array with '0' parameter   
    foreach($q as $item){
        //echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$item;echo '<br>';
        $_SESSION['list'][]=$item;//store comment_id's
        get_descendants($db,$item);
    }
}
$post_id = 199;
$comment_list = get_comment_list($db,$post_id);
print_r($comment_list);
unset($_SESSION['list']);
```

Answer (score 0):

here a single loop recursion to get posts
and a another recurse loop to show in list result
protection recurse (max 40 levels of posts)
full workable code
$database used in global to avoid big stack 
(I add a (string)field comment you can remove or replace-it, it was for test purpose)

```
<html>

 <head>
     <style>
         ul {
             border-left:solid 1px gray;
             margin-top:1em;
         }

         ul span.bold {
             font-weight:bold;
         }
     </style>
 </head>   

 <body>



<H1>POSTs TEST</H1>

<?php

// get informations
// @PARAM $startParent = first id parent, 
// @PARAM $whereToAppend = $root = array to fill
// @PARAM $level = increase each recursion, stop if greater than 40
function getComments($startParent,&$whereToAppend,$level) {

  // use global database handler
  global $bdd;  

  // secure infinite loop !
  if ($level>40) { return; }

  // get alls post with id_parent=$startParent 
  $i=0;
  // NOTE you can append a SORT tag, DESC if you want etc...
  $sql="select comment_id, parent, comment from comments where parent=$startParent";
  $result = $bdd->query($sql);
  // prepare a structure to store one post
  while ($donnees = $result->fetch()) {
   $datas=array('comment_id'=>$donnees['comment_id'],
                 'parent'=>$donnees['parent'],
                 'comment'=>$donnees['comment']
                 );

   // for more readability  
   // this post has a id            
   $id=$datas['comment_id'];

   // store the post in three
   $whereToAppend[$i]['id']=$id;
   $whereToAppend[$i]['datas']=$datas;
   $whereToAppend[$i]['sub']=array();

   // next post (always for post who has a id_parent : see parameters)
   $i++;
  }

  // now recursion...
  foreach ($whereToAppend as $k=>$d) {
        // get posts who have parent_id=id of the post found  
        getComments($d['id'],$whereToAppend[$k]['sub'],$level+1);
  }

  return ;

}


// used to show result 
// @param $start=array to iterate
// @param $level=level , always 0 at first call
function iterate($start,$level=0) {
    echo('<ul>');
    foreach ($start as $k=>$element) {
        echo("<li>");
        echo ("comment_id=<span class='bold'>{$element['datas']['comment_id']}</span><br>");
        echo ("id parent=<span class='bold'>{$element['datas']['parent']}</span><br>");
        echo ("comment=<span class='bold'>{$element['datas']['comment']}</span><br>");
        iterate($element['sub'],$level+1);
        echo("</li>");
    }
    echo('</ul>');
}



// MAIN
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

// prepare a array where to get informations
$root=array();

// get informations
// first para 0=> id parent, try with another id parent to get partial tree
// second param $root = array to fill
// third param=0, level 0 = recursion start at 0
getComments(0,$root,0);


// show informations
iterate($root,0);



?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this >

```
    //get all comments and descendants for post id
    function get_comment_list($db,$post_id) {  
            $comment_array = array();
            $sql = "SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE parent = 0 AND _post_id=".$post_id." "."ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
            $result = $db->query($sql); 
            $q = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);//one level array with '0' parameter   
            foreach($q as $parent){
                $comment_array[$parent] = get_descendants($db,$parent);
                //Use Parent ID as a key then push all childs comment under this parent ID
            }    

            print_R($comment_array);die;
        return $comment_array;
    }
    //get all descendants of parent level comments
    function get_descendants($db,$parent,$childComment_array = array()){
       if(empty($childComment_array)){
          $repliedComments = array();
       }else{
           $repliedComments = $childComment_array;
       }

        $sql = "SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE parent = $parent ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $q = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);//one level array with '0' parameter   
        foreach($q as $item){
            $repliedComments[]=$item;
            get_descendants($db,$item,$repliedComments);
        }

return $repliedComments;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't quite work.  Backwards and missing subsequent levels and not quite right.  Results came out as:  230: {
0: "235",
1: "231"
},
236: { },
237: {
0: "291",
1: "238"
},
240: {
0: "290"
},
241: {
0: "292",
1: "289",
2: "283"
},
244: {
0: "304",
1: "293",
2: "288",
3: "286",
4: "285",
5: "284",
6: "282",
7: "281",
8: "279"
},
294: { },
295: {
0: "296"
}